# Order of properties is changed in dictionary

Tags: python, properties

I'm new to python.
My current version of it is: **2.7.16**
So, in the code I have a function:

```
def func (coords):
  xb, yb, xe, ye = coords.values()
  print(coords, 'order__') #1
```

Then I call it:

```
func({ 'xb': 0, 'yb': 0, 'xe': 40, 'ye': 20 })
```

But as I found out later I got an error somewhere because the things didn't work well. I added that **print** and it showed:

```
({'xb': 0, 'yb': 0, 'ye': 20, 'xe': 40}, 'order__')
```

So, as you see the order of properties changed and that causes the destructurisation to work not correctly.
Two questions:
 1. Why is it so?
 2. What should I do to make my code work?
My solution is to make like this:

```
xb = coords['xb']
yb = coords['yb']
```

and so on. But is there a better solution? May be I don't know about it yet

Comment: Dictionaries generally don't conserve order, unlike lists. It may have been changed in python3, I don't remember. Also can try `from collections import OrderedDict`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary)

Comment: Refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared) Possible duplicate.

Comment: Actually, I don't need to keep the same order. I just want to destructurise exactly by the names.

Answer (score 2):

`dict` retains order only from python 3.7. For python versions prior to this, you can use `OrderedDict`

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dct = OrderedDict([('xb', 0), ('yb', 0), ('xe', 40), ('ye', 20)])
>>> func(dct)
```

Comment: Yes, I've heard about that. But I consider this rather excess

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries in Python are not necessarily ordered, and although ordering may work on some versions in some circumstances, you should **never** count on it. If you want to unpack the values in order, there exists [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). I don't know your situation, but maybe just use a tuple or list to hold it (since your values `'xb'`, `'yb'`, `'xe'`, and `'ye'` seem to be the variable names as well as the keys. This seems like an XY problem).

Comment: I compare it with javascript, where the code like this:
`const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const { a, b, c } = obj;
`
could work